# Переключение между экранами (Android)

Tags: android

Хотел бы уточнить, как, к примеру, в приложении ВКонтакте под android реализовано переключение между экранами друзей/сообщений/ленты новостей (снизу кнопки для переключения)?

Используют они создание нового activity и удаление старого или же как-то по-другому? (именно те переключения, которые без анимаций, к примеру с ленты новостей на сообщения).

Спасибо!

Comment: скоее всего фрагменты (Fragment)  с BottomNavigationView

Comment: [TextInputLayout](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/textinputlayout.php)